# Mono: problems trying to read a connectionString from web.config

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm fairly familiar with the .NET side of things, and am trying to do a little coding with Mono.

I am used to reading in Connection Strings from web.config using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["index"]` in .NET and am trying to figure out a way to do this in Mono.  Apparently there is no ConfigurationManager in Mono?  I have a System.ConfigurtationSettings, but the closest I can get there is AppSettings, and MonoDevelop tells me that it's obsolete.

Am I completely missing something here about how to read things out of web.config in a Mono Web Application?

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Configuration? (An actual assembly reference, not just a 'using...'?)

Comment: That would be the problem!  Thanks!

Comment: @TheNextman, this seems to be the answer. Would you mind making your comment one?

Comment: From the comments: Do you have a reference to System.Configuration? (An actual assembly reference, not just a 'using...'?)